# Log failed login attempts in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, linux, fail2ban, login-attempts

I set up a mysql 8 server on a unix shell and want to access the database by remote sql client.

For sequrity i installed fail2ban to blacklist bruteforce attacks.

But mysql wont give me failed login attempts.

I know this question was asked a lot before bit its all about mysql 5

So log_warnings is no more.

I set log_error_verbosity = 2 in mysqld.cnf but error.log just logs start and shutdoen notifications.

I read about the new error_log_components but cant figure out how it affects failed authentifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-priority-based-filtering.html#error-log-verbosity-filtering) you should set the `log_error_verbosity` variable to `3`:

> If the value is 3, the server logs aborted connections and
> access-denied errors for new connection attempts.